How to conditionally transform XAML at build time using XSLT to mirror C# preprocessor directives?
I use C# preprocessor directives extensively while developing. I define them either directly in .cs files or globally in the .csproj:
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefineConstants>fix_issue_001;fix_issue_002;</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>

Or via command line as described here.
Then I use them to compartmentalize code:
#if fix_issue_001
// some new code
#else
// some old code
#endif

This helps me track changes, though I acknowledge it's not the most readable or canonical approach. Version control and branching would be better, but we're constrained to SVN and Visual Studio.
Now I want to extend this pattern to WPF XAML files. Since preprocessor directives aren't available in XML, I'm looking at using XSLT to achieve similar functionality.
For example, I'd like to have something like this in my XAML:
<StackPanel>
    <!-- fix_issue_001:true -->
    <Button Content="Original version" Click="Button_Click" />
    <!-- end fix_issue_001:true -->

    <!-- fix_issue_001:false -->
    <Button Content="New version" Background="LightGreen" Click="Button_Click" />
    <!-- end fix_issue_001:false -->
</StackPanel>

The goal is to have XSLT transform this at build time, including/excluding sections based on whether fix_issue_001 is defined, just like #if/#else works in C#.
Requirements:

Maintain Visual Studio's XAML designer functionality
Minimize changes to existing code
Prefer solutions using .csproj/.sln and/or other configurations so it works seamlessly inside Visual Studio
Command line (batch/PowerShell) solutions are acceptable if necessary (e.g., using xsltproc or Saxon-HE)

Is this possible? How would you implement it?
P.S.1. Posted a new question here.
P.S.2. I believe I have managed to solve this problem. You may find the source code here and the NuGet package here.

Please ask a specific question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

@michael.hor257k I have prototyped some code, but it does not work as expected. I though it is better to ask before misleading others by an XY-question. But otherwise, you are right. This is not the perfect SO question.

@michael.hor257k posted a new question here.

Sorry, I thought your question was about XSLT. I know nothing about your other tags. If you want an XSLT answer, please post a [mcve] showing an example of the input, your current stylesheet and the expected output.

@michael.hor257k it is partly about the use of XSLT inside Visual Studio regarding the WPF XAML files, which are XML.

@michael.hor257k I believe I have a solution as elaborated in the P.S. above. Would you be kind to vote open this post so I can add an answer below?

FYI, I did not vote to close it.

@michael.hor257k thanks for your kind support. posted an answer below. And for your interest here is the XSLT part.

The way we do this is to add attributes to the elements.
<Button Content="Original version" Click="Button_Click" 
        v:fix_issue_010="true"/>

<Button Content="New version" Background="LightGreen"                        
        Click="Button_Click" 
        v:fix_issue_010="false"/>

I've put the attributes in a namespace here to distinguish them, but that's your choice.
The XSLT code to retain some elements and remove others is then trivial.
For example, assuming the semantics are "if 'fix_issue_010' is present in the supplied options then drop all elements with v:fix_issue_010=false", then you might use a stylesheet like this:
<xsl:transform version="3.0" 
xmlns:v="http://my-versioning-namespace/"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/2001/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="options" as="xs:string*"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="*[@v:*[.='false' and local-name()=$options]]"/>
<xsl:template match="@v:*"/>
</xsl:transform>

The xsl:mode says copy everything by default; the first xsl:template says drop elements having an attribute in the v namespace whose local name equals one of the supplied options and whose value is 'false'; the second xsl:template says drop all attributes in the v namespace.
That might not be exactly the rules you want to apply, of course.

Just like that?! There is no need to add anything else to the WPF XAML? Could you be kind to point me to an MWE/MRE? sorry if that's too much to ask.

Could you be kind to provide the XSLT code as well? It is not trivial for me being a novice in this field.

so, checking your answer I think it is a nice one, though it is not exactly what I want. I prefer using nondestructive comments <!-- <directive>:<true/false> --> ... <!-- <directive>:<true/false> as I don't want to change the old code, and the pieces of the code that I want to be omitted during the transpilation are not necessarily just one or two elements. I basically want the same functionality as #if ... #else ... #endif as in the .cs files.

I believe I have managed to solve this problem. You may find the source code here and the NuGet package here.

Its neither elegant nor exactly what you asked for but maybe you can go this direction:
<Button Content="Original version" Click="Button_Click" Visibility="{Binding fix_issue_001, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"/>
<Button Content="New version" Background="LightGreen" Click="Button_Click" Visibility="{Binding fix_issue_001, Converter={StaticResource boolToInvisibility}}"/>

alternativley you could create a converter that accepts a Name and a value as ConverterParameter and then checks the define and hides controls accordingly.
However this is your best bet, as what you request does not exist in native WPF

Thanks for the answer but this is not exactly what I asked for. This could be an answer to this question.

I believe I have managed to solve this problem. You may find the source code here and the NuGet package here.

You can now use the XamlPreprocessor NuGet package to achieve this functionality. Here's how it works:

Install the package via NuGet:

Install-Package XamlPreprocessor


Use conditional sections in your XAML files with XML comments:

<StackPanel>
    <!-- fix_issue_001:true -->
    <Button Content="New version" Background="LightGreen" Click="Button_Click" />
    <!-- end fix_issue_001:true -->
    
    <!-- fix_issue_001:false -->
    <Button Content="Original version" Click="Button_Click" />
    <!-- end fix_issue_001:false -->
</StackPanel>


Control the DefineConstants through any of these methods:

In your .csproj file:
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);fix_issue_001;fix_issue_002</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>


Via MSBuild command line:
msbuild.exe /p:DefineConstants="fix_issue_001;fix_issue_002"


Through Visual Studio's project properties under Build → Conditional compilation symbols



The preprocessor will:

Keep sections marked as true when their directive is defined
Keep sections marked as false when their directive is NOT defined
Remove all other sections

How it works under the hood
The package:

Integrates with MSBuild's XAML compilation process
Creates preprocessed copies of XAML files in the intermediate build directory
Uses XSLT to transform these copies based on defined constants
Preserves original source files (important for version control and XAML designer)
Handles proper UTF-8 encoding with BOM for XAML compatibility

The source code is available on GitHub if you want to understand the implementation details or contribute improvements.
Benefits

Works seamlessly with Visual Studio and MSBuild
Maintains XAML designer functionality
No manual preprocessing steps required
Source files remain untouched
Compatible with existing DefineConstants from C# projects

This provides similar functionality to C#'s #if/#else preprocessor directives while working within XML's constraints.
